# Ferramenta para gerar poco

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql

Tenho um banco postgres com várias tabelas e preciso gerar as classes delas.
Existe alguma ferramenta gratuita que gere os pocos para serem utilizados com EF6?
Procurei mas não encontrei. Estou usando VS2015 e postgres ultima versão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criei um pacote no nuget.org chamado "Cap" que faz o que preciso, gera os modelos e classe de contexto para usar com Entity Framework 6 e PostgreSQL. Link do [Cap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cap/).

Answer (score 1):

O próprio visual studio gera, porém você tem que trabalhar com o modelo Database First.

Adicione um ADO.NET Entity Data Model, e na próxima janela do wizard, selecione Code First from Database.

Comment: Qual provider vc usou? Eu utilizei o npgsql, mas não aparece a opção no wizard.

Comment: Eu fiz utilizando o nativo do visual studio pro SQL Server, mas se o npgsql não aparece nos providers, tem que ver se a versão com suporte ao Entity está instalada, e não sei se tem alguma outra tool no VS que tem que ser instalada.